# merging 2 data frames that doesnt have a shared column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having some trouble with merging 2 data frames that doesn't have any same column.
I have 2 data frames and I want to combine them (they both have the same row number)

For example, I have these two data frames:

A:

| store | red candy | apple |
| --- | --- | --- |
| first | 5 | 3 |
| second | 1 | 2 |
| third | 4 | 2 |

B:

| yellow candy | banana | green candy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |

and I want to merge them so I will have one data frame looks like this:

| store | red candy | apple | yellow candy | banana | green candy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | 5 | 3 | 10 | 5 | 4 |
| second | 1 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 3 |
| third | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)`?

Comment: you're the best! cant belive it so simple.. thanks a lot!